# Converting JSON Array to object using JQ

Tags: jq

I would like to ask for help. How can I transfer array to one list.
My input is

```
[
  {
    "PartNumber": "5SD30104GN114",
    "ClassificationNo": "500001",
    "StringValue": "L0035WSGE",
    "Field": "95001"
  },
  {
    "PartNumber": "5SD30104GN114",
    "ClassificationNo": "500001",
    "StringValue": "",
    "Field": "95002"
  }
]
```

And I like to expect this

```
[
  {
    "PartNumber": "5SD30104GN114",
    "ClassificationNo": "500001",
    "95001": "L0035WSGE",
    "95002": "",
  }
]
```

How Can I do ?
I tried use

> | .[] | [.PartNumber, .ClassificationNo, .StringValue, .Field]

But generate again arrays

```
[
  "5SD30104GN114",
  "500001",
  "L0035WSGE",
  "95001"
]
[
  "5SD30104GN114",
  "500001",
  "",
  "95002"
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution using reduce:

```
group_by({PartNumber,ClassificationNo})
| map(reduce .[] as $item ({}; .+($item|{PartNumber, ClassificationNo, (.Field):.StringValue})))
```

Probably not the most efficient one (part number and classification number are always overwritten), but it gets the job done while being somewhat readable.

Output:

```json
[
  {
    "PartNumber": "5SD30104GN114",
    "ClassificationNo": "500001",
    "95001": "L0035WSGE",
    "95002": ""
  }
]
```

With a function:

```
def reducer($item):
  $item|{PartNumber, ClassificationNo, (.Field):.StringValue};

group_by({PartNumber,ClassificationNo})
| map(reduce .[] as $item ({}; .+reducer($item)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group_by` to make clusters of matching IDs (I assumed `.PartNumber` together with `.ClassificationNo` to make a unique ID), then within each cluster, take the ID fields from the first item (all have the same ID fields), and add to it the values of all items by converting them to a key-value structure that can be used with `from_entries` to turn it into an object:

```bash
group_by([.PartNumber, .ClassificationNo]) | map(
  (first | {PartNumber, ClassificationNo}) +
  (map({key: .Field, value: .StringValue}) | from_entries)
)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/Fiph1rVQ1EL)

Instead of `from_entries`, you can also use `INDEX` to create an object with the right fields, but then subsequently the values need to be trimmed down to only contain the right values:

```bash
group_by([.PartNumber, .ClassificationNo]) | map(
  (first | {PartNumber, ClassificationNo}) +
  (INDEX(.Field) | .[] |= .StringValue)
)
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/8Jub36wVcMg)

```json
[
  {
    "PartNumber": "5SD30104GN114",
    "ClassificationNo": "500001",
    "95001": "L0035WSGE",
    "95002": ""
  }
]
```